# Dismissing popup interactively conflicts with UIScrollView gestures

Tags: ios, swift

how can I stop detecting dragging gesture on UIScrollView?

This is how it looks:

[image]

And when I turn off dismissing by dragging, then scroll view works pretty fine. Once I turn on dragging, then instead of scrolling UITableView it drags popup down. Why?

How can I fix that?

I am using [BottomPopup Library](https://github.com/ergunemr/BottomPopup)

Comment: What does "when I turn off dismissing by dragging" mean?

Comment: There is an option `popupShouldDismissInteractivelty `. I return there `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only enable dismiss by dragging when the scrollview's offset is 0, that is, if the user hasn't scrolled at all or if the user has scrolled and then scrolled back to top. Use the scrollview's delegate and check this value after scrolling is performed, and change **popupShouldDismissInteractivelty** according to the above.

Comment: Aww… you are very smart… I will try to do this and let you know… but it seems to be a great idea;)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work pretty but I think it is a good direction...